# How can I create a border around an Android layout like attached image?

Tags: android, list, border, shapes, layer

I have problem when i need to create border layout , but i can't .

How do I create border like attached image ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV804.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

Step 1 : create 9patch border image [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example) with blank data

Step 2 : set this image in layout background and manage padding from top, left , right and bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can border to any layout you want. Just make a custom layout with name `customborder` And add xml code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
   <corners android:radius="20dp"/> 
   <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:bottom="10dp"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
 </shape>
```

Then simply add the background to the layout like this

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder">
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know that bu i need like attached image from right and left to be white https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV804.png